# SQLite binded text value different from retrieved text value

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have the following Database class creating a database and containing methods for adding a Movie to the database. I have a couple of print statements in there for debugging too.

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

class SQLiteDatabase
{

    private var db : OpaquePointer?

    init (databaseName dbName: String){
        //Get a file handle, or create handle.
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("\(dbName).sqlite")

        //try and open filepath as databse
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            print("Sucessfully opened connection to database as \(fileURL.path)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Unable to open databse at \(fileURL.path)")
            printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        sqlite3_close(db)
    }

    func insert(movie:Movie){
        let insertStatementQuery =
        "INSERT INTO Movie (ID,Name,Year,Director) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"

        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer?
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementQuery, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, movie.ID)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, movie.name, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 3, movie.year)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, movie.director, -1, nil)
            print("Name value in is: \(movie.name), Director Value in is: \(movie.director)")

            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                print("Sucesfully inserted row")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Could not insert row")
                printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
            printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }

    func selectAllMovie() -> [Movie]{
        var result = [Movie]()
        let selectStatementQuery = "SELECT ID,Name,Year,Director FROM Movie"

        //prepare statement
        var selectStatement : OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, selectStatementQuery, -1 , &selectStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            //iterate over result
            while sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW
            {
                //create movie object from result
                let movie = Movie(
                    ID: sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 0),
                    name: String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)),
                    year: sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 2),
                    director: String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 3))
                )


                print(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)))
                print(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 3)))

                print("Name value out is: \(movie.name), Director Value out is: \(movie.director)")

                //add result to array
                result += [movie]
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("SELECT statement could not be prepared.")
            printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
        }

        //cleanup
        sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement)

        return result
    }

    func printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(_ db : OpaquePointer?){
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString : sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print ("Error:\(errorMessage)")
    }

    func createMovieTable(){
        let createTableQuery = """
            CREATE TABLE Movie (
                ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                Name CHAR(255),
                Year INTEGER,
                Director CHAR(255)
            );
        """

        //prepare statement
        var createTableStatement : OpaquePointer?  = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableQuery, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            //execute the statement
            if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                print("Movie Table Done")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Movie table could not be created")
                printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("CREATE TABLE statement could not be prepared")
            printCurrentSQLErrorMessage(db)
        }

        //cleanup
        sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
    }
}
```

I have the following code for adding two entries

```
database.createMovieTable()
    database.insert(movie: Movie(ID: 0, name: "ExtraLong", year: 2018, director: "Bob Ross"))
    database.insert(movie: Movie(ID: 1, name: "ExtraExtraLong", year: 2018, director: "Donald Putin"))
```

The issue im having is that the Output for the Name variable is actually the same as the Director variable and I cant figure out why. 
The length of the name value out is usually the same length as the name value in meaning that if the Director is longer than the name only part of the director value is assigned to the name value, albeit incorrectly.

My out put looks like this:

Name value in is: ExtraLong, Director Value in is: Bob Ross

Sucesfully inserted row

Name --> Bob Ross

Director --> Bob Ross

Name value out is: Bob Ross, Director Value out is: Bob Ross

Comment: Your code looks OK. Is it possible there is a problem with the `Movie init` function?

Comment: @rmaddy My Movie struct is defined quite simply: public struct Movie { var ID:Int32 var name:String var year:Int32 var director:String }

Comment: You must not use nil as the last parameter to [sqlite3_bind_text](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: Does it work without the Movie stuff, with plain strings?

Comment: @CL. For instance, If I set Name to string1 and Director to string2 then the out put will be string2 repeated.